# RMI between 2 JVMs on diff physical machines

Tags: java, jvm, rmi

Can anyone tell me where I should make changes in an RMI program for 2 JVMs on same physical machine to 2 JVMs on diff physical machines in the example [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/rmi/RMI.html)

@Olaf- can you help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example that you quoted has the following URI for the RMI call:

```
"rmi://localhost:1099/CalculatorService"
```

This tells your RMI client to call RMI server on the same host. If you substitute the hostname or IP address of the remote server for the "localhost", your client would call it instead.

Comment: @Olaf- thanks but I'm getting this error-RemoteException
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CalculatorImpl_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

Comment: @P Ramesh: Do you have your RMI server deployed on the other host that you are connecting to?

Comment: @Olaf-Yes, I've deployed it on the other side. In fact, executing the client program on server side works fine. only when I change the localhost to IP of server on client machine, it shows this error.

Comment: @P Ramesh do you get that exception when binding to the registry, when looking up the registry, or when calling your remote method?

Comment: @EJP I'm getting this error on the client's side after implementing the policy. This happens when I run the Client side program:
emoteException
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CalculatorImpl_Stub

Answer (score 1):

If you did it correctly, then you don't need to change anything. That's exactly what RMI is for.

Comment: Ok, but how does it know what the IP of the client machine is? Sorry for my ignorance but can you please elaborate/direct me?

Comment: You have to know the ip of the other machine and get the remote object from its registry. There are a lot of examples on the web. just google it.